# AWS ec2 instance shutting down again and again with wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have uploaded a wordpress site on `t1.micro` but there is a problem with database connectivity , It was going down multiple times(6-7 times in a day) and every time I need to restart mysql/apache server. Then I updated my instance to t2.micro to enhance the memory size but the problem was still there. Then after reading lots of forums I again decided to increase the memory size so again I updated to t2.medium

```
Model   vCPU    CPU Credits / hour  Mem (GiB)    Storage
t2.medium   2              24           4        EBS-Only
```

On many forums related to wordpress and aws, it was given that it is because of low RAM and mysql error log can help you to find out the exact issue.But when I checked mysql error log there is noting to display.

Now my RAM size is very large but the problem of shutting down server/mysql is still there.

Is there anybody who can help me to get out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you haven't given us any information to help fix this. Show your mysql configuration and relevant failure logs (mysql log, dmesg, syslog).